# Using "www" as an A record

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm having configuration issues with my website, and I'm even more confused now that I've been looking for solutions. My DNS table looks as follows:

```
A       @       12.34.12.34   600 seconds
CNAME   www     @             1 Hour
```

Currently both **mydomain.tld** and **www.mydomain.tld** work, but I would like all the queries to **mydomain.tld** to be redirected to **www.mydomain.tld**

Is there any way to do it from the DNS table or the .htaccess, or do have to code a 301 redirection as mentioned here : [A record for www](https://serverfault.com/questions/421136/a-record-for-www) ?

Could I just use "www" as an A record and @ as a CNAME ?

Thanks

Comment: You can not use a `CNAME` at the apex (i.e. for `example.com`). You can point it at 205.178.189.129 (hosted by Network Solutions) or WWWizer (http://wwwizer.com/) if you don't want to bother setting up the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect you want to setup is granted from a web server configuration; you even cited `301` as a HTTP status code, that you shall use on your webserver setup.

Trying to swap DNS zone record just won't bring any redirect: the value will reference the same webserver address, but the key player is the different value for `Host:` header in your two different HTTP requests:

1. `Host: mydomain.tld`
2. `Host: www.mydomain.tld`

So you have to configure a redirect in your webserver for `mydomain.tld`