# force all urls to www and force domain to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was trying to force my domain to redirect without www and could success through this code:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

however, this code is going to redirect all www to non-www, which is not what I want. I just want to make the main domain from **www.mydomain.com** to **mydomain.com** and the rest of the urls should be forced to www.

any idea how to add or modify the code so I can achieve that through .htaccess ?

**Update:** Thanks to all. I found out that swf file from piecemaker was corrupted and updated it with new one. so now it is all fine and works on both www and non-www. I'm still curious how to solve this issue anyways using .htaccess. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by "main domain"?  Please provide more clear examples.  What do you want to have without a `www`, and what is it now?  What do you want to have with a `www`, and what is it now?

Comment: I mean the domain itself www.mydomain.com, I have a swf file that doesn't work on www, but without it so I want to have the main page of my domain to become like this: mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com however, the code I used above force all urls on my domain to get redirected without www. now I'm still using that code above, but trying to find a way how to make it force only mydomain.com/index.html and that's it. The rest of urls should contain www. I hope it is clear now

Comment: What's wrong with ditching the superfluous "www" on all URLs?

Comment: as I know, it is not recommended for SEO. everywhere I look around for such issue, a warning message states that it is not recommended to avoid using www. It is just I have an issue with swf "peicemaker 2" www.modularweb.net/en/portfolio/piecemaker2 not working with www, but without it

Comment: @ChrisS [Plenty](http://serverfault.com/q/145777/126632).

Comment: @Digitalsite So you want to redirect the homepage to non-www, but leave all other resources alone?

Comment: yes, correct. That's all I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com/$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://example\.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this one does what the code above does; same job. it forces all urls to be redirected without www, but I want only mydomain.com