# How to generically remove the www of the domain in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a *server* config in nginx which matches several domains:

```
server {
  server_name example1.com example2.com example3.com;
  # ...
}
```

And I would like to redirect the *www* versions to the corresponding domains.
I know how to do it for a single domain with a redirect and I would know how to
do the inverse thing but I can't find a way here.

Any idea ?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Be very careful. [You probably want to do the opposite.](http://serverfault.com/q/145777/126632) Especially if you ever have aspirations of your sites being large.

Comment: I know that but sadly it's not my call :( Thanks for the link though :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `if`

```
server {
    server_name ~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$domain$request_uri;    
}
```

That's all ...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was possible to do that oO Thanks !

Comment: `~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$` will match its own redirect; remove the first question mark: `~^(www\.)(?<domain>.+)$`

Comment: Fixed in the answer.

Comment: So this can be used as global server block and it works... but how does one deal with SSL requests in different domains?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found this solution:

```
server {
  server_name www.exemple1.com www.example2.com www.exemple3.com;
  listen 80;

  if ($http_host ~ "www\.(.*)") { #Note the extra "\" after the www
    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
  }
}
```

It works like a charm :)

Comment: I would actually set up separate server blocks for each domain name. Using IF is generally bad and really non-performant with NGINX.

Comment: nginx docs kinda sucks on explaining what's going on in that if condition. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if, anyway this answer helped my case.